# add account id with uuid (django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column accounts_account.account_id does not exist)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, uuid

im trying to add account id with uuid field

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    account_id = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email                   = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username                = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    #other fields
```

but when i try to `createsuperuser` it give the following error

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column accounts_account.account_id does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...nts_account"."id", "accounts_account"."password", "accounts_...

i also did `makemigrations` and `migrate`
database are : postgis in postgresql

```
operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Account',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, 
serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, 
verbose_name='password')),
            ('account_id', models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, 
editable=False, unique=True)),
            ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=60, unique=True, 
verbose_name='email')),
```

Comment: Did you check in postgres table if the column is there?

Comment: yes , but the account_id is not added , however i did run makemigrations , and migrate

Comment: So the problem is related to migrations

Comment: but i ran migrate and the output (Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions) i removed migrations files several times still wont work

Comment: I think it's helpful to post also migration code

Comment: updated , account_id are also added !

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-showmigrations

Comment: You shouldn't remove migration files that have already been applied. It means that your database and the migration files get out of sync. Getting everything back in sync can be tricky. You could try to do this by manually creating the `account_id` column. However, if you don't have any important data in the database, it might be easiest to drop the database (back up the data if you need it), then run migrate again on a fresh database. If you're using sqlite3, just rename `db.sqlite3` (or delete the file if you're sure you don't need it).